# Search solr and sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, sunspot

I have the following questions, I have the model city (name, uf, province)'m trying to implement the method of sunspot research, but I'm getting by:

```
# modelCity.rb
searchable do
  text :name 
end 

# controller City
unless params[:search] 
  @cities = City.paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => "name ASC")
else
  @search = City.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
  end
  @cities = @search.results
end
```

city data base:

```
1 Medianeira PR 3
2 Cascavel   PR 4
3 Cascavemat PR 3
```

If I type for example "Cascavel" he brings a certain quest, but if I type in "Casca" I want him to bring all the cities that have those words related to the name. Anyone know how to do it?

OBS: Using rails 4, followed the tutorial: [git sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to configure this in the Solr `schema.xml`to compute N-grams for your text fields. Here's one possible example:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The [Solr Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) has lots of detail on this; I generally end up Googling "do x in Solr" or "why is solr doing y". Lucky for us there are a lot of smart people out there using Solr.

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot, it was not created schema.xml file

Comment: It should be in `/solr/conf`. You will need to restart solr and reindex after changing it.

Comment: Thanks it worked, one more question, if I want to search beyond the name, the province also? I tried to add the model "integer province_id" not working.

Comment: `integer :province_id` in the `searchable` block, then you can do `with(:province_id, params[:province_id])` in the search block.

Comment: not worked, typing "Casca" is returning empty, did as follows: http://pastebin.com/vE96ALXH

Comment: You have to pass just the integer that you want to equal `province_id` to the `with` clause.

Comment: Actually it does not work like I wanted, "whin" is functioning as a "where", for example:`select cities.name from cities where province_id = 2`. My objective: `select cities.name, province.name from cities inner join provinces on cities.province_id = provinces.id`.  For when `PR` is searched him so much seek in cities.name provinces.name column and also in finding these two attributes return me the city that has the word sought.

Comment: If that is the case you are going to want to index the province name as part of the city, `text :province do; province.name; end` (obviously on separate lines is fine.